# Android RecyclerView List Overlaps in PagerSlidingTabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm currently experiencing something weird on my pagerslidingtabs wherein the list I have in my recyclerview is being overlayed with the same views except that the top view is not scrollable and the list in the background is scrollable but covered. This only happen randomly and cannot be replicated easily. This can only happen if I change/swipe quickly from one page to another but as mentioned it is hard to replicate the same issue. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Now what I have is a PagerSlidingTabStrip and a FragmentPagerAdapter where it contains fragment with recyclerviews for the list. I'm pretty sure the problem is not with the recyclerview list but with the Pager itself as I guess it creates the fragment views while the previous views are not yet removed triggering this effect. I make sure to create a new instance of my fragment for my items. Here's the code so far:

```
public class ResultPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "TAB", "TAB2" };

    public ResultPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Page1.newInstance(position);
            case 1:
                return Page2.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

}
```

and the to initialize the PagerSlidingTabStrip:

```
private void initializeTabs() {
        //initialize pager
        adapter = new ResultPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs.setDividerColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        tabs.setUnderlineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        tabs.setIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        tabs.setIndicatorHeight(new Utils().dpToPx(48));
        tabs.setUnderlineHeight(new Utils().dpToPx(4));
        tabs.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }
```

and pager code:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

and the code for newInstance in my fragments that calls a webservice for data:

```
public static SenatorsResult newInstance(int position) {
        SenatorsResult f = new SenatorsResult();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }
```

Anyone experienced this problem before? hope someone can help me on this.

Comment: If you are using Collapsed ToolBar the issue is in Height. Post your xml code.

Comment: Nope, I don't use collapsed toolbar and height is actually will not be the issue even if I did use it. The answer below somehow explains the problem. The fragment is not destroyed even if it is not visible on pager which is the default behavior in android. And since it is not destroyed the layout is still visible and when I change page it will call new instance of fragment while the saved view is not invalidated which causes the problem. I'm pretty sure it's in the pager but not sure on how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.

Visit http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentstatepageradapter-example/ for more details

Comment: Okay, I somehow get the idea of destroying the fragment as soon as it is not visible but hmm. I'm not sure if this can solve the problem. I'll try it and will get back to you. :)

Comment: Tried this but the same problem appears.